# Unable to install mysql using services

Tags: java, mysql, installation

While going to install/configure mysql using services, I am getting the following error:

[image]

Please help me on this as soon as possible!

Answer (score 0):

**Probabale Reason**: log files are probably full.

**Solution**:

1. right click on “My Computer”
2. choose Manage
3. right click on Application log
4. choose Properties
5. change maximum log size to bigger value
6. check “Overwrite events when needed”

Also ,another way to debug is by looking at your log file.For more info see [this](https://cyleft.wordpress.com/2008/07/20/fixing-mysql-service-could-not-start-1067-errors/)

> Take a look at your error log by looking in:
>
> “C:\Documents and Settings\All Users.WINDOWS\Application Data\MySQL\”
>
> Then click on the “MySQL Server X.X\” folder and then “data\”
>
> Find the file [MY-DOMAIN-NAME].err and open it using notepad
>
> Another possible cause of the 1067 error might be faulty my.ini settings.

…

> So the general tip from me would be: Try to think of any reconfigurations you’ve done recently. That might be what’s causing this. —ChromaWoods
>
> We were getting a 1067 error because (we think) we’d been unable to successfully complete a reinstall after mixing up the original root password [on the mysql server].

Our solution in the end was to *completely* uninstall MySQL and reinstall. The tricky part is that the uninstall requires three steps:

1. Uninstall via Add/Remove Programs from the Control Panel.
2. Delete the Base directory — likely C:/Program Files/MySQL
3. Delete the Data directory — likely C:/Documents and Settings/All Users/Application Data/MySQL

Finding the Data directory may be a bit tricky, since the Application Data folder is hidden by default. If you change your Folder Options so you can view the Application Data folder and still cannot see it, type the path (from step 3) into Run from the Start Menu to open the folder.

Once you’ve uninstalled MySQL and deleted these two folders, you should be ready to start fresh!